# How to make netrw start with dotfiles hidden?

Tags: netrw

netrw has a `gh` command that toggles dotfile hiding. It is off by default. I would like it to be on by default. How do I do that?

Comment: Actually the `gh` command is what I needed to know, lovely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`gh` works by modifying `netrw_list_hide`, rather than by toggling a separate flag. It appends or removes the regex `\(^\|\s\s\)\zs\.\S\+`. As far as I can tell, said regex matches "a dot followed by any number of non-whitespace characters, starting either at the beginning of the string or after two spaces." I'm not sure why the two spaces, but would be interested to know.

Adding it yourself is straightforward enough:

```
" If you don't have a hide list and just want to use gh's:
let ghregex='\(^\|\s\s\)\zs\.\S\+'
let g:netrw_list_hide=ghregex

" Or, if you already have a usual hide list, append it
let g:netrw_list_hide='yourhidelist'
let g:netrw_list_hide.=',' . ghregex
```

In both cases vim will then recognize that `gh` is toggled on, and typing `gh` will turn it off.

The regex [is hardcoded](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim#L5477) and not available as a variable (unless your make one yourself, as above), so in principle this will break if it changes. That line hasn't been touched in eleven years, though. It's probably pretty safe to rely on.

(credit to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18651/20175) for pointing me in the right direction)

Comment: Works like charm

Answer (score 3):

You can try this on your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:netrw_list_hide = '^\..*'        " or anything you like
let g:netrw_hide = 1                   " hide by default
```

`help netrw-a` can give you more information.

HTH

Comment: This isn't *quite* what I asked for, but it was close enough for me to figure it out. Upvoted.

Comment: Here's a one line saving : The documentation says that `g:netrw_hide = 1` is the default, so no need for that